# Rotate 3d vector value into a single axis using a rotation quaternion

Tags: sensors, accelerometer, rotation

I want to rotate the whole value of a 3d vector into one axis using quaternion rotations.

The reason behind is that I want to align the X and Y Axis of my smartphone with the X and Y Axis of my vehicle in order to detect lateral and longitudinal acceleration separated on these two axis. Therefore I want to detect the first straight acceleration of the car and rotate the whole acceleration value into the heading axis (X-Axis) of the phone assuming a straight forward motion.

How do I achieve this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: So you know the rotation you want to apply, but just don't know how quaternions work?

Comment: @fibonatic I know that if I accelerate forward for the first time with my car, I will get the corresponding sensor value mixed on two axes (e.g. X and Y-Axes). I also know the axis I would like to put the whole sensor value in (e.g. the X axis).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use the average magnitude of X,Y as the acceleration vector.
- Get the angle between this vector and the (1,0).
- Create a quaternion with this vector that looks something like (cos(angle/2),0,0,-1)
- Multiple all future acceleration results

Comment: That is sort of the way I used to do it now. Thank you!